# Am I abusing/misusing Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm writing a program to read data from a file, which may be in one of several format (different versions of the same format, actually) and I'm using reflection for calling the appropriate function for each format. Assuming that file format is a number specified on the first byte of the file:

```
Class DataFile extends Model {
...
Blob file
...
public void parse() throws Exception{

    InputStream is = file.get();

    Class c = Class.forName("models.DataFile");
    Method m = c.getMethod("parse_v"+is.read(), (Class []) null);
    m.invoke(this, (Object []) null);
}

public void parse_v0() throws Exception{
   ...
}

public void parse_v1() throws Exception{
   ...
}
}
```

My question is, am I abusing/misusing reflection? I have the feeling that I should be using inheritance and create a different class for each file type with its own "parse" procedure, but I don't know the file type until I start parsing... and then I cannot "downcast" and just use something like `((DataFile_v1) this).parse()` so I am a little lost.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You don't need inheritence, you just need them all to implement an interface with a `parse` method and somewhere specify which parser goes to which version.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: implementing an interface is commonly called "inheritance".

Comment: Also, as you're writing this code, think of how easy it would be to write tests to make sure it does *the right thing*.  Does reflection make that easier or harder?

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: Depends on who you ask really, there's [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973861.aspx#interinher_topic3) that makes a distinction between inheritance and implementation: *Although the phrase **interface inheritance** is often used, the correct term is **interface implementation**.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this, but a more flexible and extensible way to do the same thing would be to use the version information as a key in a `Map`, and have the values in the `Map` be handler objects. Then any code can register a handler (the handlers can all implement a common interface) and your reader code can just look up the handler in the `Map` and invoke it.

Be sure to handle the case where the `Map` doesn't include a handler for a particular version!

Comment: Your solution is definitively more extensible than mine, I'm implementing it ;) thank you

Comment: +1 Once did it like that in a project and it worked pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a `DataFile` interface define a `parse` method, and implement the interface with multiple classes (`DataFile_v1`, etc.), then the calling code doesn't have to know which implementation was chosen.

```
DataFile dataFile = dataFileFactory.getForVersion(is.read());
dataFile.parse(file);
```

I'd argue that this is a better approach from a general design perspective. However, at some point you will need to create some kind of mapping between the version number and the DataFile implementations. (In this case I'm doing it in an imaginary `dataFileFactory`.) You'll have to determine whether it would be more appropriate to select an implementation using reflection or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK to use reflection here. The alternative would be using inheritance or an enum (i.e. the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)), and a map from the version code to the proper Strategy. Once you have initialized all the desired mappings, you just get the right parser object from the map and invoke it. However, setting up this solution still requires a significant amount of boilerplate code, which diminishes its readability.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't bad.  If you want to have the different parsers in different classes, you can't downcast as you say, but you could instantiate a new parser object.  So your existing class would be a facade in front of the actual parsers which aren't instantiated until you know which format you're parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection, but using reflections is looking up a collection as well.  Provided your mapping doesn't change I would use reflections.

```
getClass().getMethod("parse_v"+is.read()).invoke(this);
```